# Can I place fielders wherever I want?

Tags: rules, cricket

Can I place more than 2 midoffs or 3-4 silly points in cricket? I have seen no match with such fieldings? But there are no rules against it.

Comment: One example that you'll see in practice is two gullies. Really this is analogous to having multiple slips, the point is to blanket an area with catchers. We just happen not to use the term "first/second gully", or "forward/backward gully" to refer to the variation within the position, so we end up saying there are two fielders in the position.

Answer (score 3):

The only restriction in the Laws is that there can only be 2 fielders, other than the wicketkeeper, behind the popping crease on the on side see section 5 [here](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-41-the-fielder/).

Specific competitions may have separate regulations governing the number of players on the off or on sides.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @TrueDub, the 2 fielders only rule on the leg side behind the popping crease is mandatory for all forms of cricket, ie Test, ODI & T20. However, each format has other different fielding restrictions.

**Test cricket** - Apart from the leg side rule, there are no restrictions what so ever on fielding. You can have all the fielders on the boundary, or slips, or close in.

**ODI cricket** - Originally there were no restrictions as for test cricket however to increase entertainment poweplays were introduced starting with, for first 15 overs, only 2 fielders were allowed outside the 30 yard circle & 2 fielders must be inside the 15 yard circle(they can be slips excluding the wicketkeeper). Then changing to
During the first 10 overs of a 50-over innings a maximum of two fielders are allowed to be deployed outside the 30 yard circle. A minimum of two fielders (other than the bowler and wicket-keeper, can be slips) have to be deployed in the 15 yard circle.
The restriction of having a maximum of three fielders outside the 30 yard circle is applied for a further two blocks of five overs, Powerplay 2 & 3, with the captains of the fielding and the batting sides deciding the timing of one block each. No restrictions on the 15 yard circle is there during these Powerplay 2 & 3.
Other than the Powerplay overs, a maximum of 4 fielders are allowed outside the 30 yard circle.

**T20 cricket** - Only one Powerplay of 6 overs at the start of the innings, with two fielders allowed outside the 30 yards line & 2 fielders must be inside the 15 yard line. Outside the Powerplay overs, maximum of 4 fielders are allowed outside the 30 yard circle.

**Remember that the 2 fielders behind the popping crease on the leg side is mandatory in all formats. It was done to prevent the return of the infamous Bodyline tactics**